# What 's the equivalence of VB6 App.Path, in c#?

Tags: c#, path

How can I get the file path of .csproj in c#?

I wanna to get this info in order to check the existence of a file in that path. So If the program found that file, it means that it's in debug mode, else there is a user who is executing the program.

but using Application.ExecutablePath or Application.StartupPath or System.Reflection.....

point to a .exe file in \debug or \release path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no BCL API that will give you the path to a .csproj file. You should recall that a .csproj file is an artifact of Visual Studio, but .NET in itself doesn't rely on VS - you can compile C# applications using csc.exe, in which case you would have a fully functional .NET application without any .csproj file ever being involved.

If you want to test whether the application is running in debug mode, you can use the [#if directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx), like this:

```
bool debugging = false;
#if DEBUG
    debugging = true;
#endif
```

The `debugging` variable will only be true when the DEBUG symbol is defined, which it is when you compile in the Debug configuration. In a Release build, `debugging` would always be `false`.

However, I would consider it dubious to have such a requirement in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

VB6 created the .exe in the same directory as the project, VB.NET doesn't.  VB6's App.Path really does do the same thing as Application.ExecutablePath, it is just that the .exe is written to a different directory.  When you deploy the program, ExecutablePath will still point to the .exe, there is no "project directory" for a deployed program.

I assume you need this because your program is accessing files in the same directory as the .exe and those files are now stored in your project directory.  All you have to do is copy them, the IDE makes it easy.  Project + Add Existing Item, select the file.  In the Properties window, set Build Action = None and Copy to Output Directory = Copy if newer.

Another way is Project + Properties, Compile tab, erase the Build output path setting.  Now it will work the same as VB6.  But won't be so nice for Release vs Debug builds or your SSCS.  Don't ship the Debug build, it leaks without a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way to get the .csproj file path from the code. In most majority of the cases (after the development) the application is going to run on a machine which does not have the csproj file in it, so i don't think it makes sense for .net to expose this.

If the file that you talking about is included in your project, then you can set the "Copy to Output Directory" property of the file to "Copy always". then it will get copied to your debug or release folder when you build the project. Use Application.ExecutablePath to access it.